# Staticfiles in Django coming from npm-run-build frontend throw Error 404

Tags: django, gatsby, django-staticfiles

I want to add my Gatsby JS' `public` folder that I created with `npm run build` to be served to Django as_view. Django keeps throwing 404 Error at me when I'm trying to load the staticfiles and the index.html from STATICFILES_DIRS.

I don't understand how Django is not able to find the JSON file e.g `/app-data.json` even if I provide an absolute path.

Note: I tried `python3 manage.py runserver --insecure` (and without insecure as well) - didn't work.

Directory structure:

```
./frontend
- ./public
 - ./codeblock
 - ./codeblock/1-index
 - ./staticfiles
 - ./staticfiles/d
 - ./page-data
  - /app-data.json
 - ./index.html
 - ...

./backend
- ./backend
  -  settings.py
```

**package.json**

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "gatsby develop",
        "build": "gatsby build --prefix-paths",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,css,json}\"",
        "lint": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\""
    },
```

**settings.py**

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = False

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

BACKEND_DIR = BASE_DIR

FRONTEND_DIR = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(BACKEND_DIR, '..', 'frontend'))

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR, 'public'),
    os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR, 'public', 'page-data'),
    ]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

**urls.py**

```py
...imports 

urlpatterns = [
    url('test/', views.FrontendAppView.as_view()),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**index.html**

In the HTML file if I define the path with `/static/`, such as `href="/static/webpack-runtime-4145e7520a88c179d990.js"`, then Django can pull in the JS static files, otherwise 404 Error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link as="script" rel="preload" href="webpack-runtime-4145e7520a88c179d990.js" />
    <link as="script" rel="preload" href="commons-926e13980b7ff3c9526c.js" />
    <link as="script" rel="preload" href="app-425daa4026ff9a50d14f.js" />
    <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="page-data/index/page-data.json" />
</head>
...
```

Comment: have you used manage.py collectstatic cmd? also can you share settings.STATIC_ROOT path and set debug to True to see the detailed error message

Comment: @Houda I tried with collectstatic and serve it from root as well, didn't work. I set the debug to True as well before. I'm don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Please share the static root

Comment: @Houda, I've added the STATIC_ROOT (commented it out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here's what solved this issue for me.

- Issue 1: I didn't add **{% static %}** and **{% load static %}**
- Issue 2: I had to make changes after npm run build each time in the HTML file

**Solution:** If you are using Gatsby JS, edit your **congif.js** as seen below. It will add **/static/** before the path and Django will be able to render your pages correctly. This way you don't have to add **{% static %}** and **{% load static %}**:

```js
const config = {
    gatsby: {
        pathPrefix: '/static/'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to serve static files you need to differentiate between development (Debug = True) and production (debug = False) modes:

*If you are in a development Mode : (debug = True):*

*https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css*

*If you are in a production Mode : (debug = False):*

*https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Django Whitenoise` to serve static files in Production

Comment: It would be more useful for the community to provide more details about the tool, some links and more content.